# What is the meaning of "play Danny" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I encountered the boldfaced expression while reading, and would like to know what it means:

> The Chinese box was evasive. Sometimes it was the fretted ivories, one
> inside the other, sometimes it was a single box like a cash-box. But
> however evasive, it was important and intrustive.
>
> She’s the producer’s wife, old man. Fat. White. Like a maggot with
> tiny black eyes. I should like to eat you. I should love to **play
> Danny**. I should love to eat you. I should love to put you in a play.
> How can I put you anywhere if I haven’t eaten you? He’s a queer. He’d
> love to eat you. And I should love to eat you too. You’re not a
> person, my sweet, you’re an instrument of pleasure.
>
> A Chinese box.
>
> A sword is a phallus. What a huge mountain-shaking joke! A phallus is
> a sword. Down, dog, down. Down on all fours where you belong.

- William Golding, *Pincher Martin*, Chapter 7

I somehow guess that "play Danny" could mean "to play the role of Danny in a play".

But I am still not sure, so I searched the dictionaries and learned that "danny" (dialect) can mean "the hand." And I also learned that there is a song called "Danny Boy" but I am not sure whether it is relevant.

(There is only one reference to "Danny" throughout the entire novel, which is in this quote.)

P.S. Edited the question to provide more sentences before and after the quote.

Comment: William Golding loves allegory.

Comment: If "Danny" is capitalized, then isn't it almost certainly a proper name?

Comment: @stangdon not necessarily, it could be part of a set phrase (as in "robbing Peter to pay Paul").

Comment: Frankly, without reading the entire novel, I'm not sure I can make sense of anything in that passage. Since it mentions a "producer," it might be talking about the actual casting of a play, show, or movie. Can you give any more context or shed more light?

Comment: Suffice it to say, it is *not* an established idiom or phrase as far as I'm aware, or as far as a strict phrase search in Google Books can show.

Comment: @randomhead And aren't the capitalized parts of that phrase proper names?

Comment: @stangdon yes they are, but they do not (any more) refer to specific things. It is just a set phrase. So "play Danny" could once have meant "act like some specific person named Danny" but now means "act in [such a manner]" even if the person is no longer deliberately referencing someone they know personally. See "take the Mickey" which is sometimes capitalized and sometimes not.

Comment: @AndyBonner " without reading the entire novel, I'm not sure I can make sense of anything in that passage" - maybe not even then, by the look of things. Golding had a very tricky style - "What most drew me to Golding’s novel was the astonishing prose-poetry of his style, and the extreme density of overlapping metaphors which he weaves to create the heightened sensory world of a drowning man, and which induce in the reader the same confusion" says [an article about setting this novel to music](https://william-golding.co.uk/setting-william-goldings-pincher-martin-to-music)

Comment: Oh dear, a spoiler?

Comment: @AndyBonner - my comment above was intended generally and not aimed at you. What I meant was that the language is, it seems, so very allegorical and so very poetic that you're not meant to 'make sense' of it. And there's a reason, and you find out at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. Actually, this is the one and only time in which "Danny" appears throughout the entire novel (I searched "Danny" in my Ebook and found only one result, which is this quote). So I think that it might be a proper name, but... there is nothing else in this book as to who this "Danny" might be. (The producer's name appears to be Pete, by the way.) Or probably it could mean "act like a specific person/character in the play called Danny" as you suggest. In case this might be helpful, I would edit the question to contain more sentences before and after the quote.

Comment: @ReadingGlasses - have you grasped that there may be a lot in this book that you are not going to understand, and which nobody can explain?

Comment: @ReadingGlasses - "Fat. White. Like a maggot with tiny black eyes. I should like to eat you. I should love to play Danny. I should love to eat you. I should love to put you in a play. How can I put you anywhere if I haven’t eaten you? He’s a queer. He’d love to eat you. And I should love to eat you too. You’re not a person," - Just look at it! This is the kind of nonsense blank verse stuff one hears (or reads) in one's head while drifting off to sleep, when entering a dream state.  It _isn't meant to make 'sense'_. You need to grasp this fact.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much for the comments. Hmm, it does seem like a blank verse that goes through his consciousness. Then I think I would just have to throw a guess at it... I am guessing that "Danny" might be a character/part in a play, because there comes "I should love to put you in a play," but I am not sure.

Comment: @ReadingGlasses - I would guess that 'playing Danny' might be like 'playing King Lear' or 'playing Othello', but it could equally be like 'playing Scrabble'. Or not. This is stream-of-consciousness stuff. Are you aware of the whole plot?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much for the comment. So "play Danny" would be like "play King Lear", and "Danny" would be the role/name of a character in a play, probably. Yes, I read the book till the end, but I thought I could not understand it properly after reading only once, so I am re-reading it again... :D